# Transform Multiple Asymptote Surfaces Simultaneously?

Tags: asymptote

Is there a way with `asymptote` to combine two surfaces, so so that I can transform both simultaneously? E.g., below I would like to say `surface r = cp+cm;`, then do `r=rotate(45,Y)*r;` instead of separately rotating both surfaces.

```
% To run: pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=RotateTwo}
settings.outformat="png";
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=10;

import three;
//Setup View
size(200);
currentprojection=orthographic(1,-3,2);

//Draw Axes
pen thickblack = black+0.75;
real axislength = 2.0;
draw(L=Label("$x$", position=Relative(1.1), align=SW), -axislength*X--axislength*X,thickblack, Arrow3); 
draw(L=Label("$y$", position=Relative(1.1), align=E), -axislength*Y--axislength*Y,thickblack, Arrow3); 
draw(L=Label("$z$", position=Relative(1.1), align=N), -2*axislength*Z--2*axislength*Z,thickblack, Arrow3); 

//Define cube surfaces
surface c1 = shift(-0.5X-0.5Y-0.5Z)*unitcube;
c1 = zscale3(0.1)*c1;
surface cm = shift(-0.25Z)*c1;
surface cp = shift(+0.25Z)*c1;
surface rm = rotate(45,Y)*cm;
surface rp = rotate(45,Y)*cp;
//I'd like to just do rotate(45,Y)*(cp+cm)

//Draw cube surfaces
draw(rm,palegrey);
draw(rp,palegrey);
\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `surface` structure allows to concatenate surfaces, `surface(s1,s2,s3,...)`. In your case

```
surface ccp=rotate(45,Y)*surface(cm,cp);
```

O.G.

Comment: "You can try" doesn't convince me that you know it works. Do you think you could test it on the code provided by the OP, and if it works, include the working version as a complete example?

Comment: OK. I changed my message. I tested, I read some pieces of `three_surface.asy` and it works.